# Pandas - Join on multiple unique columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes:

```
   x_1  x_2      x_3    x_4        x_5  ID  x_count
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93             10        1
1  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz  10        2
2  159  xyz  94mmm4k             heavy  15        2
3  354  abc  94mmm4k                     3        1
4  354  abc  94mmm4k   455h             15        1
5  354  abc  94mmm4k             super   3        1
6  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g             10        1
```

And:

```
   y_1  y_2      y_3    y_4     y_5  ID  y_count 
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93          10       55
1  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93  lightz  10       14
2  159  xyz  94mmm4k          heavy  15       2
3  354  abc  94mmm4k                  3       7
```

I am looking to join both tables and do math on the count columns, I am not sure what would be the best method to join these two tables. If you notice the x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 columns have unique values that are being accounted for in the count column and each of their instances, the table with the y columns matches on some of the same unique instances found in the table with the x columns

Here is what I was hoping the new dataframe would look like:

```
   x_1  x_2      x_3    x_4        x_5  ID  x_count y_1  y_2     y_3    y_4   y_5   ID  y_count
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93             10        1 159  xyz  883nne2 28h93         10      55
1  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz  10        2 159  xyz  883nne2 28h93  lightz 10      14
2  159  xyz  94mmm4k             heavy  15        2 159  xyz  94mmm4k         heavy 15       2
3  354  abc  94mmm4k                     3        1 354  abc  94mmm4k                3       7
4  354  abc  94mmm4k   455h             15        1
5  354  abc  94mmm4k             super   3        1
6  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g             10        1
```

I've tried merging on the ID column and left join but it just duplicated these records and did give me the result shown above.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose dataframes are df1 and df2 respectively. You can do a left merge using all the columns like this

```
df1_merge_cols = ['x_1','x_2','x_3','x_4','x_5','ID']
df2_merge_cols = ['y_1','y_2','y_3','y_4','y_5','ID']
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1_merge_cols, right_on=df2_merge_cols, how='left')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! this is the correct answer!